# Number prototype definition

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain me how to overcome this thing?

```
String.prototype.one = 1;
"one".one; //returns 1

Number.prototype.one = 1;
1.one; //returns 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the interpreter sees a `.` after a number as a decimal, not a property accessor, so it sees it as this:

```
(1.)one  // SyntaxError
```

Give it another `.`, and it'll work.

```
1..one
```

It now sees it as this:

```
(1.).one
```

Other solutions:

```
1.0.one
1["one"]
(1).one
```